# Getting error "No such module" using Xcode, but the framework is there

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, xcode

I'm currently coding in Swift, and I've got an error:

> No such module Social

But I don't understand, because the module is in my project, declared in "Linked frameworks and Libraries" and in "Embedded Binaries".

The frameworks is in Objective-C, so I wrote a Bridge Header for it.

Please, how can I make Xcode recognize the framework?

[image: Error module]

[image: Project]

[image: Linkes Frameworks, Libraries]

[image: Header bridge]

Comment: Not to be too mr. obvious but have you tried a full clean and build?

Comment: That was my first reaction :)

Comment: If the framework header is already included in the bridging header file then you don't have to import it in the Swift source file.

Comment: You are right, it was just a "desesperate code", because nothing worked.

Comment: Also you might have to use quotations marks for the import: `#import "Social/Social.h"`

Comment: It can't be because Social is a framework so it is with <>, but I tried what you said and it doesn't work at all :/

Comment: Using Xcode 8.1, I got the same issue. Problem was, the framework was build with Swift 3.0 instead of 3.0.1 ;-)

Comment: I have faced this issue in watch app and resolved it by: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39944607/apple-watch-no-such-module-alamofire/40738216#40738216

Comment: Watch your derive data and check that the framework is being copied into your /Frameworks folder under your project in the iphonesimulator. If it's not, then you're not properly linking it or the binary is not compatible. If it is, then it's a path problem and you need to check your framework search paths.

Comment: I changed Deployment Target from 11 to 10, but forget it in Podfile `platform :ios, '10.0'`. That was solution.

Comment: pod install
 it worked for me.

Comment: A very simple problem can be that: when you drag the framework from say your desktop in to Xcode, it does NOT copy it to the relevant project directory, but just leaves it on the desktop.  Ensure you have "copy to location ..." when you drag it in!

Comment: I was stuck on this problem with XCode 10.3, I think I've tried all the solutions I found on the internet and in this thread for about 4 days.
It could be weird, but I fixed it by changing the project path: I simply placed the project 2 or 3 folder outer than before. It seems that the Swift compiler could not reach that nested folder level.

Comment: LOL - I had this problem with Xcode 12.4 and SQP AppCenter. I had to close and open the xcworkspace several times. From the third one the import worked...

Comment: You can try the top answer of this ask. [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65978359/xcode-error-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-in-dylib-built-for-ios-f)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69927210/10632772

Comment: If you are getting this issue only on Simulator and not on real device, this answer might fix this issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/77701983/10738935

Comment: Also, if you are trying to build on  Apple Silicon Mac

Answer (score 412, accepted):

I'm not sure why this happens, but one way to solve your issue is to go into your **build settings** and defining the **Framework Search Paths** to a folder which contains the frameworks in question. If the frameworks are placed in your project directory, simply set the framework search path to `$(SRCROOT)` and set it to recursive.

Comment: Thanks. I had to do this in my project build settings rather than my target build settings

Comment: The trick for me was finding a path to the framework to use in the Framework Search Paths. ${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/YourFrameworkName.framework works well for me. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32816507/how-do-i-create-a-development-framework-in-ios-including-swift

Comment: @malhal 
1. Make 'Embedded Content Contains Swift Code' - Yes Under Build Settings
2. Set the framework search path to $(SRCROOT) [Note: only include path don't include xxx.framework]

Comment: That worked, thanks. I didn't need to change the path, just setting to recursive fixed it

Comment: So I'm including my framework as a sub-project, then I have it built as a dependency, my solution was to use ../../build/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME) to find the correct framework

Comment: NOTE ON THE FIX: $(SRCROOT) only worked for me when I added it to the Framework Search Path FOR THE PODS PROJECT.

Comment: Try this: comment out the `import` line, build (lots of errors), uncomment the `import` line and build. This seems to "kickstart" the compiler into seeing what's in front of it's nose.

Comment: $(SRCROOT) , recursive, also for "*Header Search Paths*" worked for me!

Comment: OMG! **The real fix (for me at least) was: 1. Firstly,** reset App's `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` to be just `$(inherited)` and nothing custom. **2. Secondly,** Add to Framework both `SUPPORTS_MACCATALYST = YES;` and `DERIVE_MACCATALYST_PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = YES;` (i.e. click it's project, then *Editor* menu's *Add Build Setting > Add User-Defined Setting* option).
**3. Lastly,** we needed to change `LD_DYLIB_INSTALL_NAME` (i.e. *Dynamic Library Install Name*) setting to `$(DYLIB_INSTALL_NAME_BASE:standardizepath)/$(EXECUTABLE_PATH)` value. **Note:** skip second step if not using `Catalyst`

Answer (score 879):

In case it's Friday afternoon or anytime after 1am:

Opening `xcodeproj` instead of `xcworkspace` will cause an error like this...

Comment: I tried this as a holy grail. Funny. Who knows but exiting then reopening the workspace actually worked as well. Clean, then build.

Comment: This happened to me after Xcode crashed and I selected 'reopen' application from the bug report. I will know better next time.

Comment: Also applies to building on the command line (our problem): xcodebuild -workspace yourproject.workspace.

Comment: I often used `xed folder`, and it looks like this reads the `xcodeproj` file instead of xcworkspace`. When I explicitly used `open -a finder folder` and clicked `xcodeproj`, it worked fine. No xcode 'clean' required.

Comment: For those who are building from cli using `xcodebuild`, specifying the workspace i.e., `-workspace <>`, did the trick.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69927210/10632772

Comment: OMG yes! I tried to extract a part of app into a framework, and thought I could get away with adding that project into app project. Nope. Two separate projects (in subfolders), one workspace, open only that one.

Comment: I usually open the /ios directory and it picks the right one but looks like it doesn't with the latest update. Thanks for saving me at least a couple of hours!

Answer (score 122):

Make sure that the naming of you configurations in the sub projects matches that of the "parent" project. If the configuration naming don't match exactly (case-sensitive), Xcode will abort the archive process and show the error "No such module ..."

That is, if you have a "parent" project with a configuration named "AppStore" you must make sure that **all** subprojects also have this configuration name.

See my attached screenshots.

[image: Configuration setup in "parent" project]

[image: Configuration setup in 1st sub project]

[image: Configuration setup in 2nd sub project]

Comment: In my case, the subproject had only `Debug` and `Distribution` and its parent project was trying to build for `Release`. Solution was to make a copy of `Distribution` in the child project and rename that copy `Release`.

Comment: This led to me finding the issue, but I solved it by adding to the framework search paths in my custom configurations since I didn't want to touch a 3rd party subproject :)

Comment: This is the correct answer in case you have a subproject (in my case subproject with a framework), because when .framework is built it is located in a different build folder when configurations do not match that's why Xcode can't find framework (module)

Comment: I have project with structure like this(not like in answer - **AppUI** and **AppDomain** live without nested to App): 
-App.xcodeproj
-AppUI.xcodeproj
-AppDomain.xcodeproj

So this answer works for me when I did so and added **AppUI.framework**, **AppDomain.framework** to **App** in section `Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded content`

Comment: Man thank you, one long day of frustration saved!

Answer (score 52):

<sub>I am not quite sure why [Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r)'s answer in the comments for the question is so disregarded:</sub>

Make sure that you tried simply *skipping import of the framework as it is already added with the bridging header*.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 47):

I had the same issue using Cocoapods and **Swift**. I didn't notice the following lines in the Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
# use_frameworks!
```

So, all I had to do was change it to:

```
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!
```

...aaand it worked :)

Comment: Yeah for me use_frameworks wasn't even in my Podfile so I added it

Answer (score 37):

The following steps worked for me.

1. Quit xcode
2. Run `"pod update"` in terminal
3. Open `.xcworkspace` and build again.

Answer (score 27):

Please compare this screenshot with your build setting.
It may this work.
Go to the framework search path:

[image]

Comment: Also mentioned by [Chris Prince](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500227/getting-error-no-such-module-using-xcode-but-the-framework-is-there#comment53470207_31077255).

Comment: This really helped me thanks. But reminder for other readers: After doing this, delete your Derived folder, and restart Xcode.

Comment: For me works when I added `SnapKit` to: 

1) `Frame Search Paths` -> "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/SnapKit" 
2) `Header Search Path` -> "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/SnapKit/SnapKit.framework/Headers"
3) `Other C Flags` -> framework "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/SnapKit"

Answer (score 21):

In my case, after many attempts to figure out what I was doing wrong importing a framework I eventually discovered that the framework itself was the problem. If you are not getting your framework from a trusted source you should inspect the framework and ensure that it contains a Modules folder with a module.modulemap file inside it. If module.modulemap is not present, you will get the "No such module 'MyFramework'" error.

[image: Example showing directory structure of SwiftyJSON.framework]

If the Modules folder is missing the "MyFramework.swiftmodule" folder then the framework will be found but Xcode won't know about its contents so you will get different errors.

Comment: For some reason this isn't shown in xcode 9.1 even when it's present.  Right click on your framework > Show In Finder > and make sure your modulemap is there.  If you're using a manual framework in a pods project, rebuild your pods if you've just added a new manual framework or updated an existing one.

Answer (score 21):

I was experiencing this problem as well.  The fix for me was that the Archive schemes between the two projects didn't match.  I have an xcworkspace with a framework project and an app project.  The problem was that in the Archive scheme for my app, I was using a different Build Configuration than the framework was using for it's Archive scheme.  I set both Build Configurations to Release, and that fixed the issue.

Comment: Our framework didn't have the AdHoc configuration we used for the project - which meant it didn't build together with the project.

Answer (score 21):

**Xcode compile error: No such module**

```
//Swift
import <module_name> //No such module '< module_name >'
```

It is compile time error. You can get it in a lot of case:

- `.xcodeproj` was opened instead of `.xcworkspace`
- `module.modulemap` or `.swiftmodule`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47036023/what-is-export-in-module-modulemap-file-inside-each-framework/59213694#59213694)

**Objective-C Library/Framework Target**

make sure that generated binary contains `module.modulemap` file and it's headers are located in `Build Phases -> Headers section`

**`Framework Search Paths`**

consumer -> framework

If you try to build an app without setting the `Framework Search Paths`(consumer). After setting the `Framework Search Path` to point to the framework resources, Xcode will build the project successfully. However, when you run the app in the Simulator, there is a crash for reason: `Image not found`[<sup>about</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216681/4770877)

It can be an absolute path or a relative path like `$(SRCROOT)` or `$(SRCROOT)/..` for workspace

**`Import Paths`**

Swift consumer -> Swift static library

The `Import Paths`(consumer) should point to `.swiftmodule`

**`Find Implicit Dependencies`**

When you have an implicit dependency but `Find Implicit Dependencies` was turned off

**CocoaPods**

- Check if this dependency is existed in a target

```
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

**CocoaPods `UI Test Bundle`**

for `App Target` where used additional dependency from CocoaPods. To solve it use `inherit!`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56273013/4770877) in `Podfile`

[[Recursive path]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57516845/4770877)

Comment: 1. Open ProjectName.xcodeworkspace
2. Product -> Build

Comment: What solved it for me was opening with `.xcworkspace instead of .xcodeproj`

Comment: In my case, I had to add a module to the `Link Binary With Libraries`.

Answer (score 17):

Assuming the Framework really is there and in the path, etc... delete the ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache directory (and clean the project and delete the project-specific derived data for good measure).

When you do the standard cleanup, the ModuleCache directory doesn't get rebuilt.

Comment: I just did it as you told me, and it doesn't work :/

Comment: Then you may be facing a different problem that just looked the same as the one I encountered. :-/

Comment: I was having the same issue with a Cocoapod and deleting the files in ModuleCache did the trick for me.

Answer (score 17):

For me **Build Active Architecture Only** was set to Yes for the selected configuration. This did the trick:

Select "Pods" from the left project navigator > Select "Build Settings" > Build Active Architecture Only to **No**

Comment: It's the trick for old projects on m1. Because old Pods uses old architecture, they may not support the m1 on their old versions.

Answer (score 15):

Be sure, that `Find implicit Dependencies` in Build options in Scheme is on!

Comment: You saved my plenty of hours. Actually to speed up my code 12, I unchecked **Find implicit Dependencies** as per some solutions over stackoverflow. But after reopening the project its starting to complain.

Answer (score 15):

There are several potential misconfigurations the issue can arise for,

1. Please confirm that you have opened the `.xcworkspace` but not `.xcodeproj` file. Also make sure you have build `Social` first before you build `TriviaApp`.
2. Make sure that iOS Deployment Target is set same for all modules with main app. For example is `TriviaApp`s deployment target is set to `9.0`, `Social`s deployment target also need to be set to `9.0`.
3. Make sure your main module (`TriviaApp`) and your used framework (`Social`) have same set of configurations. i.e. If your Project has three configurations, `Debug`, `Release`, `ReleasePremium` than your Social framework also need to have three configurations `Debug`, `Release`, `ReleasePremium`. Also make sure that the archive configuration is set same for both `TriviaApp` and `Social`. i.e. if your `TriviaApp`s archive scheme is set to `ReleasePremium`, your `Social`s archive scheme also need to be set into `ReleasePremium`.
4. Please assure that you do not need to import `Social` in each `.swift` files when its already added in the `Bridging-Header.h`.
5. In case of issue came from Pod files, make sure you have uncommented `#use_frameworks!` into `use_frameworks!` from you `Podfile`. Sometime re installing pod works if `Social` has any dependency on pods.
6. If none of the above steps works, [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39495772/1084174) your derived data folder and try re building.

Comment: In my case besideds #3 I also had to check that Excluded Architectures matched both modules (TriviaApp and Social in this example). Hope it helps!

Answer (score 12):

What worked for me is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30809206/cocoapods-pod-install-modules-cannot-be-imported?rq=1) solution to another question. Closing Xcode and reopening the project as workspace. 
 Go to your project folder and open `.xcodeworkspace`  file. 

Once you open the workspace (instead of project), Pods should appear as top level project in Project Navigator.

Answer (score 10):

As for xCode 12 and simulators,

the error might disappear when you navigate to Pods.xcodeproj in project navigator,
and in build settings under the 'Excluded Architectures', for every Debug and Release, chose 'Any iOS Simulator SDK' with value arm64.

Comment: For me, removing the following from my `podFile` fixed it:

          installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
      end

Comment: I tried all the solutions above but only this one worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Resolve issue of **Webview of apple iOS xcode Version 12.3 (12C33)**

**METHOD 1**:Simply Do 3 steps:

1. Open project with `.xcodeproj`
2. Quit Xcode
3. Reopen project from `.xcworkspace`

**Done**

**METHOD 2**: Simply Do 3 steps:

1. Open podfile -> Add `use_frameworks!` in podfile -> save pod file
2. Quit Xcode
3. run `pod install`
4. Reopen project from `.xcworkspace`

**All Done**

Comment: does not fix it

Comment: This worked for me! But the problem came back again as soon as I did "clean build folder"

Answer (score 7):

I also encountered the same error a few days back. Here's how I resolved the problem:

The error is "module not found"

- Create Podfile in your root project directory
- Install cocoapods (a dependency manager for Swift and iOS projects)
- Run pod install
- Go to Project Build Settings:

  - Find Objective-c bridging Header under Swift compiler - Code Generation (If you don't find Swift compiler here, probably add a new Swift file to the project)
  - Drag and drop the library header file from left side to bridging header (see image attached)[image]
- Create a new bridging header file: e.g TestProject-Bridging-Header.h and put under Swift Compiler → Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name (ref, see the image above)
- In TestProject-Bridging-Header.h  file, write #import "Mixpanel/Mixpanel.h"
- In your Swift file the code should be:
  Import Mixpanel (i.e name of library)

That's all.

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes `pod deintegrate` and then `pod install` helps me, too.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, how the same problem was resolved for me was to set the derived data location relative to the workspace directory rather than keeping it default.
Go to preferences in xcode. Go to locations tab in preferences and set Derived data to Relative.
Hope it helps.

Comment: It worked only once, then when i run goes to the same issue of not finding the module.

Answer (score 6):

I was getting same error for

```
import Firebase
```

But then noticed that I was not adding pod to the main target section but only adding to Test and TestUI targets in Podfile.

With the command

```
pod init
```

for an xcode swift project, the following Podfile is generated

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MyApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyApp

  target 'MyAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'MyAppUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

So, need to make sure that one adds pods to any appropriate placeholder.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this with

Targets -> General -> Linked frameworks and libraries

Add the framework which should be at the top in the `Workspace` folder. Pain in the arse.

Answer (score 5):

If you're building for a platform like tvOS, make sure you have an Apple TV (i.e. matching) simulator selected.

Building a tvOS app with an iOS simulator selected gave me exactly this error. Spent the better part of an hour looking for all sorts of build issues... doh.

Answer (score 5):

I was getting the same error as i added couple of frameworks using `Cocoapods`. If we are using Pods in our project, we should use `xcodeworkspace` instead of `xcodeproject`.
To run the project through xcodebuild, i added `-workspace <workspacename>` parameter in `xcodebuild` command and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

In my case the app the IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET was set to 9.3 whereas in my newly created framework it was set to 10.2

The implicit dependencies resolver ignored my **new framework** because the requirements of the target platform are higher than the app requirements.

After adjusting the framework **iOS Deployment Target** to match my application deployment target the framework compiled and linked successfully.

Answer (score 5):

I was having a similar issue with xcode 10.3. xCode was unable to recognise files from pods. Here I have solved this way:

- Go to Build Phase
- Link Binary with Libraries
- Add framework from pods (in my case EPSignature.framwork)
- Clean & build the project

Error is gone. 
[image]

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR: Check your Podfile for target-specific `shared_pods`**

After beating my head against the wall and trying literally every single other answer posted here over the last week, I finally found a solution.

I have two separate targets - one for release and one for development. The development target was created long after the release target, which lead me to forget some setup steps for that target.

I was able to get my project to compile properly using my release target, but my development target was having an issue.

After looking at my Podfile for the twentieth time, I noticed that I only had the following, under my `shared_pods` definition:

```
target 'Release' do
  shared_pods
end
```

What I needed to do was add my second target to my Podfile, and that fixed the issue:

```
target 'Release' do
  shared_pods
end

target 'Development' do
    shared_pods
end
```

Hopefully this saves someone a few days of frustration.

Comment: shared_pods depreacated

Answer (score 4):

I found that the `Import Paths` in the `Build Settings` was wrong for a custom (MySQL) module. After pointing that to the right direction the message was gone.

Answer (score 3):

I just removed the frameworks by removing references and again added them.

Answer (score 3):

I just deleted my cocoapod. Then, I did a pod install to remove it. Then, I just added it back into my podfile and re-installed it. That made it work. Not sure why.

Answer (score 3):

I had already installed pods. Build worked without any problems when I builded application on my device, but archive didn't work. I just run:

```
pod install
```

no new pods were installed, just .xcodeproj file got regenerated and archive started working

Answer (score 3):

If you have more than one project in workspace, you need to:

1. **add new configuration to all of the projects**
2. *product* -> *clean*
3. delete `derived data`
4. `pod install` in terminal
5. build your project.

Answer (score 3):

In General => Linked Frameworks and Libraries, I added my `./Pods/Pods.xcodeproj` and it did the trick

Answer (score 3):

In Xcode 10.1 the solution for me was to change the **build system** on **Workspace Settings** in the File menu. It is by default set to **New Build System**, changed that to **Legacy Build System** and that did the trick.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Surprised this even worked. My solution was to go to ...

**Build Settings -> Framework Search Paths -> highlight debug -> press delete -> it should automatically fill out a path. -> Do the same for release**

Result: 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that worked for me **using M1 machine** was to run Xcode using Rosetta.
 Without that, I was able to run the app only on real device, but not on the iOS simulator.
 Building the app can be a little slower but it resolves the issue definitely.
If you dont know how to turn the Rosetta on, here are the steps:

- Quit Xcode
- Find Xcode in `Applications` folder, right click on it and press `Get Info`
- Tick the `Open using Rosetta` as it is shown on the image below
- Open Xcode again and run your app

Not sure if deleting derived data and cleaning the project is necessary, but you can also do it.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2):

This is what finally worked for me.  Its pretty lame that I had to do all this, but this was the only thing I could find that worked.

After ensuring the library was listed under `linked framework and libraries`.  If its not there you can click the `+` and hopefully see your framework/pod listed.

[image]

Click on your project in the scheme icon (see image below)

[image]

Then you should see your framework of focus listed:

[image]

Click `Manage Schemes.`

Then you should see something like this:

[image]

Tick the `box` for your framework, click `AutoCreate Schemes now`, then `close`.

Then try to import your framework/pod again.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Carthage, the frameworks in building setting usually stay in

`$(PROJECT_DIR)/Carthage/Build/iOS`

If you run `carthage update --platform ios --no-build` (to save time) the files inside Build folder will not be reacreated, then the modules will no available to XCode.

In my case, I have run `carthage update --platform ios`, then my problem was solved.

Answer (score 2):

For me going to Edit Scheme ->  Run, and changing the debug configuration to Debug from Release fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Most of the other answers are for CocoaPods or Carthage users**. If you are **NOT** using either of these, but just want to drop a framework in your project and link against it, it will need to be in a f**ramework search path**.

The system frameworks are already in the search path (namely `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS${version}.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/`). If the ones you are trying to use are not in this path, you need to add their path to `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` in your Build Settings.

---

*Why doesn't XCode knows where to find it without this even though the framework on your left panel has a location and full path listed in the Identity and Type in the right panel? That... I don't know.*

Answer (score 2):

In rare cases this error might be fixed by setting proper platform here [ProjectNavigator]->[**Project**]->[**Target**]-> (Architectures) **BaseSDK**

[image]

When creating a framework I've chosen accidentally wrong template (as I was creating macOS framework previously) because it was set to like my previous choice. When adding a target it is easy to miss out configuring platform so double check that.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Check whether you are using latest version of xcode.(If not update to the latest version supported by your device).
2. Install cocoapods with `sudo gem install cocoapods`
3. Run `pod setup`

I can confirm that the above steps solved my error :-)

Answer (score 2):

In the Target's build settings Set the **"Framework Search Paths"** to *$(inherited)* and recursive.
[[image: 1]]

Answer (score 2):

For me the answer was to go to the **Targets**, first check do the target name and the project name match, if they do, then go to **General** -> **Frameworks** and add them manually. When I did that, I clean build the app, and everything was working fine. Unfortunately, none of the answers before resolved my issue, so maybe this can help you as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth (I'm new to this using Xcode 7.2/Swift 2), but I noticed that just having the .swift file from the library in the project directory automatically gives you access to it and does not need the using statement.

Example: I'm using SwiftyJSON and just having the SwiftyJSON.swift file in the project was all I needed. The `using` statement was actually giving me the 'no such module' error and taking it out resolved it, and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with loading FacebookSDK, I added **~/Documents/FacebookSDK** (search where your frameworks are) to **Framework search paths** in **Build settings** and after that I was able to import the FBSDKShareKit module

Answer (score 1):

IF you have done everything above and still nothing worked for you then try adding `$(inherited)` in Framework search path of your target's build setting.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was. Inside of the targets -> Build Settings -> Framework Search Paths and adding $(inherited). However if it is a cocoapods your answer probably inside of output in terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completing with another possibility, this error might happen when the option "Find Implicit Dependencies" is unchecked. Go to Edit Scheme -> Build.

[image]

Then check this options.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you have to install the Pods.

1. Open terminal
2. cd project
3. pod install
4. Open .xcworkspace and
5. Build is succesful

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem while developing a custom Pod. Found that I just needed to specify the dependency in my Procfile:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
   # ... other declarations

   s.dependency 'Alamofire', '~> 4.3'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this issue because I set the wrong target in the podfile (the project itself rather than the UITests section).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was simply that some of the projects that used the framework had a deployment target iOS version previous to the deployment target iOS version of the framework. Once I changed the framework deployment target iOS version, the error went away.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

My problem (this time) was that I used an outdated version of the library in my Podfile.

I used:

```
pod 'LBTAComponents', '~> 0.1.9'
```

which didn't work, but when I changed it to:

```
pod 'LBTAComponents', '~> 1.0.2'
```

it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I try every suggestion above still not working.
I just copy the file's content which show the error without the import stuff and paste it to another file with same imports and comment the error file out.
Run the project again it worked, then I delete the original error file and create a file with same name and make it's content back again with the same imports.
I think in my case I just figure a way to let it be able to link those imports once and it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen when the framework does not compile properly.

Open the framework project in Xcode and see if `Product → Build` succeeds.

Once you have fixed the build errors in the framework, open the main project and see if you can import the framework.

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution for my case some minutes ago.
The project was an objective c project with cocos2d framework.
None of the previews solution works.

Just I delete the VALID_ARCH row at User-Defined at Build Settings and the project start to build on simulator.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For those who have multiple targets, check if framework was added on the right target. (in Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content).

Answer (score 1):

For me what resolved the problem was selecting the pods module (from the left of where you choose a target device) and run build on it. Once the building was done, I switched back to my own module, build it and there was no error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

For me this occurred on RxSwift and the issue was I had fixed it to 3.0.0 in the Podfile. Removing the version restriction and update the pods upgraded it to 3.1.0 which fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also be caused by the framework lacking a module map. If the framework you are trying to import is yours, check for compiler warnings on the framework itself. In my case my framework was building and in place, but there was a build warning:

> warning: no umbrella header found for target 'MyFramework', module map will not be generated

By resolving this warning (which [related to the framework header not matching the module name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30704268/no-umbrella-header-found-for-target-module-map-will-not-be-generated)), I was able to import the framework.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just had to reload the project. I had used command-line to clone my project, but it didn't install the submodule correctly. To remedy, I cloned the project through XCode, and everything works. Just make sure you back up any changes first.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your podfile, remove the pod that creates a problem, and save the file
2. Run pod install
3. Re-add the pod, save the file
4. Re-run pod install

Answer (score 0):

In my case with project on swift 4 libraries weren't compiled so it wasn't possible to find them and import.
The solution was to set compile version for libraries of cocoapods as swift 3.2
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I installed the pod Fakery, the pod got added under my Pods file, however when I tried to use it I got the same error. Problem was, I didn't build it, after building it , the swift compiler threw a few errors in the Fakery swift files that some functions have been renamed, it also provided fixes for them too. After resolving all those compiler issues , build succeeded and I was able to use the module. So swift language compatibility was the problem in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I win the award for dumbest cause of the "No such module" error. In my case I build the included framework by hand, and copy it into my project directory. My framework search paths were set correctly, and the framework was added to the project correctly.

When I archived the framework I was building, I used "Show in Finder" to take me  to the release folder in derived data. But I didn't noticed that the folder contains only an alias to the framework, not the framework itself. The original framework remained in my derived data directory, so later when I cleared derived data the framework was deleted, but *my project didn't know that*.

Re-archiving the framework, following the alias to the actual framework, and copying that to my project directory worked.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just simple project, without cocoapods, like I had, 
u can try to move your framework inside your project directory and re-link. 
I had it on a desktop, but linked and "import MyFramework" made an error. After moving it inside project directory and linking it again, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved this much more easily by adding to the end of `build-debug.xconfig`

`#include "../Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-IAP/Pods-IAP.debug.xcconfig"`

And to the end of `build-release.xconfig`

`#include "../Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-IAP/Pods-IAP.release.xcconfig"`

since those files already define `PODS_ROOT` and the related build variables.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause in XCode 10 can be the `Supported Platforms` sometimes gets changed to `macOS` and the `Valid Architectures` gets changed to `i386 x86_64` for the Pods Projects. Assuming the project is for iOS, then select the Pods Project and change the `Supported Platforms` to `iOS` and the `Valid Architectures` to `arm64 arm64e armv7 armv7s`, You could do each of the Targets, however that takes longer if you have more than one Pod. Also the `Swift version` of frameworks in written Swift sometimes gets set to the wrong version.

Answer (score 0):

One more suggestion for Xcode 10+ and projects that 1. created with Xcode version <10, 2. Contain a subproject with a framework that the main project depends on. The issue is that Xcode will place the compiled framework in the directory specified in the subproject, which is likely different from the main project build directory.

Check File > Project Settings. Now, click "Advanced..." and select something other than "Legacy" as the build path, for example, "Unique". In that case Xcode will put all builded components into one folder and it should be able to find the "missing" module.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I fixed it be replacing any tilde (~) characters in my Custom Paths with `$(HOME)`. Custom Paths are located in the Xcode preferences under the **Locations** tab.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not able to make archive from xcode but **fastlane** did the work for me

Answer (score 0):

After trying all the ideas on this thread, it worked when I updated cocoapods.

```
$ pod --version
$ 1.0.0 // should have been 1.10.0
```

You should update cocoapods

```
gem which cocoapods
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the folder where the project is and delete the plugin causing the error there. For me, I deleted the Google Mobile Ads Sdk folder that caused the error and the problem was fixed. It was enough to include it with pods.

Answer (score 0):

[Sazzad Hissain Khan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1084174/sazzad-hissain-khan)'s 3. option adding the same "Build Configurations" in the App's framework than in the App solved my "Unknow module" issue.

[image]

This post helped me to understand how to add new build configurations, since going to Editor -> Add configuration was greyed out

[Adding a build configuration in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842746/adding-a-build-configuration-in-xcode)

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was because the project file was missing this file "coursesX.xcworkspace"

When I added it and re-opened the project everything worked well

Answer (score 0):

In my case:
The issue only occurs on Xcode 12.4, but not Xcode 13.
one of the framework of test target gives this error after I rebuild that framework for arm64 simulator support (in XCFramework format). I fixed it by update the path in `Framework Search Paths`

```
"$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/WireTesting.xcframework/ios-x86_64-simulator"
```

to

```
"$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/WireTesting.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use CocoaPods, try to comment out (#) the new pod, run pod install, bring it back and pod install again. Sometimes somewhy pod script does not produce correct dependencies (or is in conflict with running xCode?) so it -sometimes- does help

Answer (score 0):

You added the dependency (module) to your pod, but without a version (either specific or range).
Please define the version, run `pod install`, and open the `.xcworkspace` file not `.xcodeproj` file

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had 2 xcode installed `v14` and `v15`. I was trying to open a project in xcode 14 which was using `SwiftData` which was supported only in Xcode 15. Make sure that you are not opening a project which uses apis' supported only in the latest versions of the xcode.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cocopods try to find any wronging when you are updating or installing your pods via terminal.  Warning messages that appeared on the terminal suggested to add

```
$(inherited)
```

to both FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS and HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS for both Debug and Release. Everything work fine after that.[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your issue comes when running project on Simulator and on Apple Silicon Mac AND issues goes away when you run on real device.

This might be simulator architecture issue.

1. You need to support both type of destinations [image: Here is image for that]

2. After setting this option you might still get an error that says "You need to install rosetta". please run this command on terminal `softwareupdate --install-rosetta` and run again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this kind of error on my react native project and I deleted Podfile.lock file and pod install again and its works.

Answer (score 0):

**== SwiftUI and Using SPM(Swift Package Manager) ==**

I had already added using SPM but still I faced this issue.
I had the same issue, not sure if it will help you but try
**Project -> TARGETS("Project name")**
**Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content**.
Check if there is "Supabase" under Name if not try to add it by clicking the plus icon.

[image: supabase image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error for Flutter and for Firebase
I tried all the answers and none of them worked for me.
After many trials, my problem was that the development certificate of the Apple developer account was expired, I believe it is Xcode new version (15) problem because when I have an old mac not updated. when I opened the project on the old xcode (14) it gave me the error straight away.

In my case the solution was simple, go to the [Apple developer certificates page](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/list)

Make sure that all certificates are not expired, and if you find any expired certificate, click on it and select revoke.

When you open the project if you already enabled automatic syncing it will create a new cerificate for you.

I hope this helps someone, I spent days searching for the solution.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your project folder is not in iCloud Drive.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -3):

I went through the above solutions but unfortunately, nothing helped me. What I did later

1. close the project.
2. From the terminal, go the project directory and run below command:
3. *git reset --hard origin/master* (i wanted to change in **master** branch.)
4. *git fetch*
5. *git checkout master*
6. *git pull origin master*
7. Open the project(of course from Xcode)
8. Clean build and remove derived data.
9. Build the project again.

yes, I know some commands are redundant. But spending 2 days and pulling my hair out is much worse than those steps.