# Xcode 7.1.1 - Custom iOS framework not found when building for Generic iOS Device / Archive

Tags: ios, xcode

I have imported my universal custom iOS framework to a new sample project. The sample program can be built in simulator and execute without problems.

However Xcode returns 'No such module ' when I try to archive or build the project in Generic iOS Device. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Update: 2015-10-17 17:55
Finally I found that the script I wrote to to create the universal framework does not include arm and arm64. And it causes Xcode unable to build the project in archive or build in Generic iOS Device.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode : "No such module" error, but the framework is there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500227/xcode-no-such-module-error-but-the-framework-is-there)

Comment: Still build fail even following the solution of the post

Comment: It is impossible to help you until we know all the paths you are going to use and even then the only solution that one could ever give you is to take these paths and add them to the frameworks search paths. Don't just copy the solution from the answer linked above, apply it with adjustments to your own configuration. If you are sure that's what you've done, edit the question and add the details so that everyone can see it.

Comment: Finally I found out there is a problem for my universal framework. I am going to modify my script and hopefully the problem will be fixed.