# No such module 'OneSignal'

Tags: ios, cocoapods, onesignal

I'm trying to integrate [OneSignal SDK](https://onesignal.com) in Xcode 7.2.1 with CocoaPods 1.0.0.beta.2 and `use_frameworks!` directive. 
When I try to import the framework in AppDelegate.swift I get

> No such module 'OneSignal'.

I also have other frameworks included from Cocoapods which work with no problem (ex: Fabric)

I managed to install OneSignal SDK with cocoapods in another project, but without the `use_frameworks!` directive. I used the bridging header.

Comment: Just a stab in the dark, but I've always had to build the project after installing new pods before I can import them. This was the case again when I installed the OneSignal SDK using #use_frameworks. Hope it helps

Comment: I've noticed that too. But I built and rebuilt the project several times, cleaned  it and the build folder, restarted Xcode. No luck so far.  @Ollie , does OneSignal work for you with #use_frameworks ?

Comment: I've got the #use_frameworks in my podfile as I have other pods that work with that, although to use OneSignal I also had to use a bridging header. I realise my first comment was maybe a little misleading!  (Sorry!!) They specify in the getting started guide that you need a bridging header in swift. https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/installing-the-onesignal-ios-sdk

Comment: You should post this as an answer. I managed to do it by adding the bridging header. I thought the bridging header is not needed if you have use_frameworks. Actually I didn't think it was possible to have both use_frameworks and bridging header. Silly me

Comment: Ok will do, glad it's solved!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pods written in Swift can be imported with the `use_frameworks!`, and CocoaPods will complain if you don't do this and try to import the pods in Swift code.

Although any pods not written in Swift, will require the use of a bridging header.

Referencing to the OneSignal pod, the getting-started guide  instructs applications using Swift to include a bridging header in order to use the pod. [OneSignal: Getting Started Guide](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/installing-the-onesignal-ios-sdk)

Comment: Top level within the podfile

Comment: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/using-onesignals-xcframework-for-mac-catalyst

Answer (score 16):

With OneSignal `5.0.0` (on Flutter) I had to use:

```swift
import OneSignalFramework
```

instead of

```swift
import OneSignal
```

Answer (score 12):

You need to type these commands. It has fixed it for me:

```
$ pod deintegrate
$ pod install
```

My Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Your_Project_Name' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks

  # Pods for Das Gedenken
pod 'OneSignal'


end

target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
  #only copy below line
  pod 'OneSignal'
end
```

Answer (score 6):

if you have already pod file before starting development OneSignal, you need to add new target for OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.

```
    target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension
  pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.5.2', '< 3.0'

  end
```

After the adding above code to the podfile. You must "pod install" one again.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to mention is that [Getting error "No such module" using Xcode, but the framework is there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500227/xcode-no-such-module-error-but-the-framework-is-there)

> If the framework header is already included in the bridging header file then you don't have to import it in the Swift source file.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT

Is OneSignal cocoapod written in Swift or not? Do I need `use_frameworks!` or bridging header? What works in Xcode 8.2.1, Swift 3 and OneSignal (1.11.3) ?

1. [OneSignal: Getting Started Guide](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-setup) did not actually work in Swift 3
2. adding `import OneSignal` to `AppDelegate.swift` actually didn't work for me
   (no autocomplete & compilation error)
3. `use_frameworks!` is of no help in this specific situation

#### Xcode 8.2.1, Swift 3, OneSignal 1.11.3

- Use this bridging header <sup>(†)</sup>:

  ```
  #import "OneSignal/OneSignal.h"
  ```
- In the App Delegate:

  ```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
                   launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?)
                   -> Bool {
      _ = OneSignal.init(launchOptions: launchOptions,
                         appId: "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx")
      ...
  }
  ```

---

- <sup>(†)</sup> *An easy way to add a properly setup bridging header is to simply add a new Objective-C source file to the project and follow the dialogs.*
  [image: Configure bridging headers]

Comment: there is already a valid answer specifying the use of a bridging header. why would you post another one?

Comment: Good point. Answer is about the specifics of what the bridging header actually contains, and how the invocation looks in Swift 3, in direct conflict with OneSignal tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for this. Helped me.

Answer (score 0):

BUILDING(CMD+B) the project immediately after installing the pods before start using the pod helps. And also we have to clear all the error before start using the pods.

Answer (score 0):

try this out:
Go to Product > Schemes > New Scheme...
Select the name of your Cocoapod then click OK.
After you do this, build the project.

Answer (score 0):

```
target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'OneSignalXCFramework', '>= 2.5.2', '< 6.0'
end
```

while adding your code into the podfile make sure to check the compatibility with your dependency in the pubspec.yaml file.