# 'No such module' error when module is there swift

Tags: swift, module, google-calendar-api

I am attempting to install the Google Calendar API using Swift. I am attempting to run the sample they placed online https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/ios?ver=swift#step_2_prepare_the_workspace

However, I am seeing the error, "No such module 'GoogleAPIClient'" However, the folder is clearly in the project directory. Please help. Screenshots below [image]

[image]

Comment: Can you try the solution provided in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500227/xcode-no-such-module-error-but-the-framework-is-there). One of the solution says "Opening xcodeproj instead of xcworkspace will cause an error like this".

Comment: @noogui I don't see xcworkspace in my project directory...do you know what may cause that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module could not be read because the pod install was not successful. This appears to be due to the version of ruby that was being used at the time. Updating ruby and re-running 'pod install' solved this issue.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you did to solve that problem? I am facing the same problem with the Drive API

Answer (score 1):

Try to add

```
 #import <GTMOAuth2/GTMOAuth2Authentication.h>
```

in your Bridging-Header.h

Comment: I don't have that file. I seem to have had some sort of error when building the pods. I got this error "TypeError - Unable to convert Ruby value `"GTMOAuth2"' into a CFTypeRef." Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: to add this file drag any .m file to your project

Comment: No it isn't. This did not add a bridging header to my file

Comment: drag any .m file to your project when drag it the following will appear

Comment: you can use this link to add bridging-Header.h file https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-create-an-objective-c-bridging-header-to-use-code-in-swift

Comment: It actually looks like I'm having a pods issue that stems from the version of ruby I was using.