# No such module CWNotificationBanner

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add [CWNotificationBanner](https://github.com/charliewilliams/CWNotificationBanner) to my app. So I downloaded the library using pods and now its available in my project. But I can't import `CWNotificationBanner` in my app delegate. It gives me error no such module. [image]

But I can see pods folder is there. How can I solve this issue? 
Please help me.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode : "No such module" error, but the framework is there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500227/xcode-no-such-module-error-but-the-framework-is-there)

Comment: I checked this. But still I couldnt solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You have to add all binaries to library required to use banner. Check weather any of them you missed or not. This error generally occurs because of not adding binary into library. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is after you run your `pod install` you still work with your `yourproject.xcodeproj` file. You should run your Xcode with the new generated file `yourproject.xcworkspace` after pod installed. There won't be an error