# Unable to import bridging header

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Im trying to link an external Objective-C framework, "frameworkSDK", to my swift project. However I seem to be getting this error :

```
<unknown>:0: error: failed to import bridging header
```

I've looked at loads of solutions to my problem but non of them seem to work. Here's what I've done so far :

- I've created a "bridingfile.h" at the root of the project and
  imported "frameworkSDK.frameworkSDK.h" to the file.
- I've made sure Objective-C Bridging Header path was correct under
  Swift Compiler - Code Generation.
- I've changed my framework search paths to the where the 
  "frameworkSDK" is located - Code Generation.
- Added the path to "bridgingfile.h" to Header Search Paths - Code
  Generation.
- I've tried to instead create the bridgingfile 1 directory in from
  the root folder, and then update accordingly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: your bridge file name should be `ZoomBridgingHeader.h`

Comment: the best way to create bridging header is to drag drop the Objective-C source files into the xcode. but if you want to do it your self. create the bridging header and add it to the build settings of your project

Comment: I've tried both methods but non seem to work ;/

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing an external Objective-C framework, i.e. one stored in, say, `frameworkSDK.framework` directory structure (bundle), you should not have to worry about a bridging header.  Instead do the following:

- Under Build Settings set Framework Search Paths to the parent
  directory of the `frameworkSDK.framework` directory.
- Also under Build    Settings set Runpath Search Paths to
  `$(FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS)    @executable_path/../Frameworks`.
- In a Swift file where you want to    use the Objective-C framework do
  `import frameworkSDK`.

Comment: I've tried what you suggested, but then I get an error : "No such module frameworkSDK". I've looked at solutions on stack to this problem but none of these seem to work : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500227/xcode-no-such-module-error-but-the-framework-is-there