# adding UnityAds to my Swift game project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unityads

i am trying to ad Video reward ads using UnityAds to my swift game project , so i copied the sdk and the bundle to my project and then went to my gameviewcontroller file and added

```
import UnityAds
```

but i keep getting an error saying  no such module 'UnityAds'

so i tried adding a bridge to my project and named it bridge.h and added this line of code to it

```
#import <UnityAds/UnityAds.h>
```

and it still doesn't work , and i feel i am missing something but can't find what it is, can someone help me please

Comment: Try this and answers given here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/31077255/3411787

Comment: Hi Naeim - could you share the error you're seeing, please?

Have you seen our tutorial for swift projects?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dhxivc9wWZ8

Comment: @Brandon yes i did see it and i followed every step and I can't seem to import the UnityAd , i think it's not reading the sdk and I don't know why

Comment: @NaeimSalib - i added an answer with a link to the current releases - note that the modern SDK doesn't provide a bundle, so double-check to make sure you're using 2.0. if you're using the latest, it's probably just a missing checkbox on 'Copy items if needed' that's giving you the 'no such module' error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you reference a bundle, it seems that you are attempting to integrate SDK 1.5 according to the SDK 2.0 instructions.

Get the latest 2.0 release from [here](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/unity-ads-ios/releases).

Follow the video integration guide [here](https://youtu.be/Dhxivc9wWZ8?t=79), note that dialog at 1:19 - ensure that you have the 'Copy items if needed' checkbox selected.

Comment: I have used latest version now , but still no such module