# No such module JSQMessagesViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I'm trying to import JSQMessagesViewController:

```
import JSQMessagesViewController
```

And it gives me the error 'no such module'. I've seen many people with this problem on the web but I can't find the solution. Here's my podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, ‘9.2’
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift 
use_frameworks!

target ‘IXODES’ do
 pod 'JSQMessagesViewController'
 pod 'Firebase'
 pod 'Firebase/Core'
 pod 'Firebase/Database'
 pod 'Firebase/Auth'
 pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

end
```

I've tried cleaning the build, also `pod deintegrate` and then `pod install` and `pod update`. Nothing works and I can see the library in my project like the rest. Any help?

Comment: Do any of the other pods work?  Try commenting out your JSQMessagesViewController dependencies and see if you can access the Firebase module.  This could be a problem like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500227/getting-error-no-such-module-using-xcode-but-the-framework-is-there)

Comment: Are your opening the `*.xcodeproj` or `*.xcworkspace` file? You should be using the latter...

Comment: @ForestKunecke Yes the other pods works fine.

Comment: @PauloMattos I'm using the workspace but I've tried both of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps you tried to import the file and the file is missing by any chance, 
a few things you can do.
you can clean the project from cocoapods and re-install cocoapod(this helped me onetime i got the same problem the file were missing) you can do that by

run this code on the terminal

```
[sudo] gem install cocoapods-deintegrate
```

once done

```
cd your file
```

and then run this`pod deintegrate`
then you're all set! and re install it

---- another solution ---

try these

1-Adding all of the .frameworks to the Projects Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries

2-Selecting each framework and building it. You can do this by selecting your project name next to the run arrow.

3-Cleaning the project and restarting my computer.

hope it helps

Comment: what pod are you trying to import?

Comment: JSQMessagesViewController

Comment: can i have its link ?

Comment: try these -- 1-Adding all of the .frameworks to the Projects Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries
2-Selecting each framework and building it. You can do this by selecting your project name next to the run arrow.
3-Cleaning the project and restarting my computer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139182/discussion-between-rawand-ahmad-and-jaime-alcantara-arnela).