# "warning: no targets to build in package" error in swift package manager

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, socket.io, swift-package-manager

I am trying to install SocketIO into my swift 4 iOS project using the swift package manager.  The Package.swift file looks like this:

```
// swift-tools-version:4.0
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyApp",

    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift", .upToNextMajor(from: "12.0.0"))
    ]

)
```

On command line when I type 'swift build' the packages are fetched but there is an error:

"warning: no targets to build in package"

When I try to import SocketIO in my app I get:

"No such module 'SocketIO'" error.

This is my first time using Package Manager.  Just wondering how to resolve this and whether or not I need to add targets myself in the Package.swift file?

Not sure if I set up Package Manager correctly initially.  Also wondering if there is a way to uninstall and reinstall Package Manger?  Or is it just a matter of replacing the Package.swift file in the project directory.

Comment: Did you try to clean project and delete DerivedData?

Comment: I have now deleted the DerivedData and tried again but same message.  "warning: no targets to build in package"

Comment: restart the Xcode  , clean and build hope resolve the project

Comment: restarting and clean/build not solving the issue.

Comment: would you try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500227/getting-error-no-such-module-using-xcode-but-the-framework-is-there

Comment: @alionthego There is an issue generated on this topic:
https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift/issues/827

Can you follow up on this.

Comment: thanks Irfan, tried that link but having same issue with no resolution.

Comment: Add comment on that issue. I created this issue on GitHub from your this question. They will reply.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try the following:

- Use `.Package` instead of `.package`
- Use `majorVersion: 12, minor: 0` instead of `.upToNextMajor`

## Code:

```
import PackageDescription

 let package = Package (
    name: "MyApp",
    dependencies: [
       .Package(url: "https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift", majorVersion: 12, minor: 0)
    ]
)
```

## Output:

If successfully built the following will be created:

- `Package.resolved` will contain the packages used
- `.build` hidden directory is created, these will contain the build files.

## Tested on:

- Swift 4.0

## Refer:

https://swift.org/getting-started/#using-the-package-manager

Comment: error: type 'Package.Dependency' has no member 'Package'
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift", .upToNextMajor(from: "12.0.0"))

Comment: Which version of Swift are you using ? Are you on linux or Mac ?

Comment: Mac and swift 4.0

Comment: Couple of points to note, Swift Package Manager only supports Mac app at the moment

Comment: oh....  I didn't know that.  Maybe that's why the dependencies are not being linked.  Thanks very much.

Comment: No, that's not the reason why you get that error. Why are you using `.upToNextMajor` ? Can you see the answer that I have provided

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155744/discussion-between-user1046037-and-alionthego).

Comment: I just want the SocketIO framework in my chat application. All was working fine prior to Swift 4 where previously I manually added the files to my project. Not I can no longer manually add them because of some frameworks I also need so I need to use Cocoapods or Package Manager. I wanted to avoid Cocoapods.  I tried your solution but it didn't work.  The dependency is from the SocketIO GitHub page

Comment: the Package.resolved and .build are created with my original code, however the import SocketIO returns an error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

I found documentation for SPM v4.

By this [link](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/PackageDescriptionV4.md)

So, you should try this:

```
// 1.0.0 ..< 2.0.0
.package(url: "/SwiftyJSON", from: "1.0.0"),

// 1.2.0 ..< 2.0.0
.package(url: "/SwiftyJSON", from: "1.2.0"),

// 1.5.8 ..< 2.0.0
.package(url: "/SwiftyJSON", from: "1.5.8"),

// 1.5.8 ..< 2.0.0
.package(url: "/SwiftyJSON", .upToNextMajor(from: "1.5.8")),

// 1.5.8 ..< 1.6.0
.package(url: "/SwiftyJSON", .upToNextMinor(from: "1.5.8")),

// 1.5.8
.package(url: "/SwiftyJSON", .exact("1.5.8")),

// Constraint to an arbitrary open range.
.package(url: "/SwiftyJSON", "1.2.3"..<"1.2.6"),

// Constraint to an arbitrary closed range.
.package(url: "/SwiftyJSON", "1.2.3"..."1.2.8"),

// Branch and revision.
.package(url: "/SwiftyJSON", .branch("develop")),
.package(url: "/SwiftyJSON", .revision("e74b07278b926c9ec6f9643455ea00d1ce04a021"))
```