# Xcode, No such Module

Tags: swift, xcode

Im getting the `No such Module` each time i try to `build/build for testing` the project on my iMac, but when i run the exact same project (project is on iCloud drive) in my Macbook pro everything seems to be working perfectly.

Both computers are on macOS high sierra

Both Xcode are 9.0.1

My Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'

target '___' do
        use_frameworks!
        pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift', '~> 12.0.0'
        pod 'SkyFloatingLabelTextField'
        pod 'SwAlert'
        pod 'RealmSwift'
        pod 'ESTabBarController-swift'
end
```

i've tried:

1. deintegrating the project using pod deintegrate
2. add the frameworks to the linked frameworks and libraries tab
3. deleting the derived data folder
4. updating all pods
5. moved the project to a folder on the machine (not in icloud drive)
6. removing and reinstalling Xcode
7. setting the search path to `$(SRCROOT)`

with further investigations i've found that the derived data folder is missing all *.framework files for my pods so i've copied the derived data folder from my macbook pro (working properly) and move it to the imac, to the surprise it seems to be fixed the `No such Module` error but a new error is showing up `missing required modules: 'SSCZLib', 'SSCommonCrypto'`

How Can i fix it ?
**PS: im using the `.xcworkspace` file**

Comment: can you check your project path does not have a blank space

Comment: this is the full path of my project 
/Users/iMac-HOH/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com\~apple\~CloudDocs/xxx\ yyy/iOS/pending/Q4C/Q4C.xcworkspace

Comment: it looks fine., also can you check https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift/issues/754

Comment: Try installing the pods in iMac.

Comment: the pods are installed on the iMac , ive been running pod install on iMac more than once

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting error "No such module" using Xcode, but the framework is there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500227/getting-error-no-such-module-using-xcode-but-the-framework-is-there)

Comment: ive tried setting the search path to $(SRCROOT) but that didnt solve the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the problem by building my `pods-projectname` file separately

1. edit scheme
2. choose `build` from the list on the left
3. add `pods-projectname`
4. press close and then build for testing the `pods-projectname` file.

Comment: This worked great for me because it was able to point out which file was missing from the pod.