# No such module 'Mapbox' after upgrade to xcode 9

Tags: ios, mapbox, xcode9

I have upgraded xcode to 9, now my project using [mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/install/ios/) has the compiler error as mentioned in the title.

I have installed mapbox as embedded binary and using Carthage without any success :-/

Versions:

1. Xcode 9.0.1
2. Mapbox 3.6.4
3. Swift 3.2

Comment: It wasn't specific related to mapbox but it couldn't find any framework

Answer (score 1):

Ok fixed it editing the Framework search path as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500227/getting-error-no-such-module-using-xcode-but-the-framework-is-there)
Xcode is .... :-/

Comment: NOTE ON THE FIX: $(SRCROOT) only worked for me when I added it to the Framework Search Path FOR THE PODS PROJECT