# "No such module" when achieving (builds fine)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I know this question has been asked before but my problem is only when archiving. My project builds and deploys fine to my development devices. If i comment out all references to this module, it complains about another module (e.g. IQKeyboardManagerSwift). If i comment out this one, the next module and so on. I've checked the folders (e.g. Debug-iphoneos and Release-iphoneos under the library directory) and they are identical. I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500227/getting-error-no-such-module-using-xcode-but-the-framework-is-there) but it didn't help.

[image]

Comment: "I've tried this but it didn't help." You've tried _what_? There are a lot of answers there; did you do all of them? In any case, your question adds nothing to the mix. — Also, pay attention to the `@objc` warning please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500227/getting-error-no-such-module-using-xcode-but-the-framework-is-there "This" is a link to what I've tried

Comment: If this is an exact question then point me to it!!!