# Getting No such module 'AWSS3' in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have installed AWS for uploading documents from my iOS app. So, I have followed **Swift-Amazon-S3-Uploading-Tutorial** and it's installed successfully by pods, but, after imported the framework into my class, it's throwing as "No such module 'AWSS3'", even I removed derived data as few forums suggested, and I have done all possible ways like clean, build, but, nothing helped me.

I followed this tutorial

https://github.com/maximbilan/Swift-Amazon-S3-Uploading-Tutorial

Can anyone suggest to fix this?

Comment: Have you done Product > Build yet?

Comment: clean and build your project again.

Comment: I tried already nothing helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer finally, after recheck my pod file, I was added the pod files at

```
  target 'projectname' do
    inherit! :search_paths
```

instead of under

```
use_frameworks!
```

finally fixed and the added the version number too for that pod files as following suggested link

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

   target :'YOUR-APP-NAME' do
      use_frameworks!

      pod 'AWSS3', '~> 2.6.13'   # For file transfers
      pod 'AWSCognito', '~> 2.6.13'   #For data sync

      # other pods . . .

   end
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-user-data-storage.html

Answer (score 1):

When I get no such module using cocoapods it because I opened the project with the **.xcodeproj** instead of with **.xcworkspace**

Also you may need to ensure the framework path is correct. This has happen to me before with Cocoapods

[Getting error "No such module" using Xcode, but the framework is there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500227/getting-error-no-such-module-using-xcode-but-the-framework-is-there)