# Mapbox not found. @mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl doesn't build iOS project on CircleCi

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, mapbox, circleci

I've been trying to fix an issue happening on CicleCi when I try to integrate [@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl](https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl) on my project.

Locally MapBox works builds and works fine. But only on CircleCi, the build doesn't work.

```
▸ /Users/distiller/project/packages/my-project/node_modules/@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl/ios/RCTMGL/RCTMGLCallout.h:11:9: fatal error: module 'Mapbox' not found
▸ @import Mapbox;
```

The error happens on both Xcode 9.3 and 10.1.0. And I had tried via both manual and Cocoapods setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After almost 20 different trial and error, and all related to module/framework resolving on Xcode - following basically StackOverflow posts [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500227/getting-error-no-such-module-using-xcode-but-the-framework-is-there), I realized something: `https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl/tree/master/ios`

What happens is: [`Mapxbox.framework` is installed from a `npm` `preinstall` hook](https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl/blob/master/package.json#L29). So I figured out that this was not being called somehow from CircleCi only. I don't know yet if it's a lerna or a CicleCi issue.

A not ideal solution that I found for it was: call mapbox's script to download the framework manually before the ios build (`npm explore @mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl -- npm run fetch:ios:sdk`).

Comment: This should be solved in 7.2.0+ as @react-native-mapbox-gl/maps now uses cocapods, no npm presinstall hook