# Embed a framework in a cocoapod framework project

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I have an application which is using a library installing via `Cocoapods`.

In that library project, now I have embedded a framework and it build successfully.

Back to my application when I do `pod install` then build. The library pod show me error:

> No such module 'embedded framework'

in the swift file which I used that framework.

I have research and try many solutions but still not work. How can I bring the embedded framework along with my library project?

Add link binaries:

[image]

Add copy files:

[image]

Still error in the main application when compile:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500227/getting-error-no-such-module-using-xcode-but-the-framework-is-there ?

Comment: @Amit yes I did but it's another story, my story is that I want to embed a framework in my library project not my application project

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Xcode project General Tab. Check for Embedded Binaries.
Now, Add your missing lib. or framework here.
Check in screenshot below.
[image]

Clean and run the project.

Comment: in library project, there's no embedded binaries :v

Comment: Yes there click on + button and add you lib or framework.Clean and run the project.