# Swift Build Error - No such module 'Feature1'

Tags: ios, module, compiler-errors, frameworks

I am getting compile error when I added a framework into my app. Framework `Feature1` is built successfully but from module `App` import is not working.

[image]

How to solve this issue?

Comment: This might be helpfull - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500227/getting-error-no-such-module-using-xcode-but-the-framework-is-there

Comment: Can you describe how you add Feature1 framework to App?

Comment: @SerhiiLondar i just imported as they are in the same workspace. Should i do any extra step? Feature1 and Feature2  (frameworks) worked fine when called from one another without any extra step. But when i import to App (single page project) did not work though.

Comment: Please check "Frameworks, Libraries And Embedded Content" section in General tab in your application target settings. Maybe you forgot to add your framework there.

Comment: @SerhiiLondar I should embed only for application target? from framework to framework call this it not required?

Comment: Yes. You should embed your framework for your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several potential misconfigurations the issue can arise for,

1. Please confirm that you have opened the `.xcworkspace` but not `.xcodeproj` file. Also make sure you have build `Feature1` first before you build `App`.
2. Make sure that iOS Deployment Target is set same for all modules with App. For example is `App`s deployment target is set to `9.0`, `Feature1`s deployment target also need to be set to `9.0`.
3. Make sure your main module (`App`) and your used framework (`Feature1`) have same set of configurations. i.e. If your Project has three configurations, `Debug`, `Release`, `ReleasePremium` than your Framework also need to have three configurations `Debug`, `Release`, `ReleasePremium`. Also make sure that the archive configuration is set same for both `App` and `Feature1`. i.e. if your `App`s archive scheme is set to `ReleasePremium`, your `Fearure1`s archive scheme also need to be set into `ReleasePremium`.
4. Please assure that you do not need to import `Feature1` in each `.swift` files when its already added in the `Bridging-Header.h`.
5. In case of issue came from Pod files, make sure you have uncommented `#use_frameworks!` into `use_frameworks!` from you `Podfile`. Sometime re installing pod works if `Feature1` has any dependency on pods.
6. If none of the above steps works, [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39495772/1084174) your derived data folder and try re building.