# xcode ios 'No such module GoogleSignIn'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an ios project that works good but after i push it to git hub and clone it again from other computer i get this error

**'No such module GoogleSignIn'**

[No such module GoogleSignIn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgnle.png)

Comment: Install the dependencies into that other computer.

Comment: Are you using Cocoapods to install GoogleSignIn?

Comment: review if you are using GoogleSignIn, because if you are not, you have to remove from AppDelegate

Answer (score 1):

Open your project in terminal app and do `pod install`

Another possible solution: open `xcodeproj` file instead of `xcworkspace` and check again

Comment: when i use pod install again the framework duplicate and i get more errors

Comment: Did you try to remove Pods folder in finder and run `pod install` again?

Comment: yes i did that 
i deintegrate the pod and install it again but still more errors

Comment: I would recommend to try other solutions from that [stackOverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500227/getting-error-no-such-module-using-xcode-but-the-framework-is-there)

Answer (score 0):

Try Following things:

1. Clean the Xcode project using `Command + Shift + K`
2. Install the dependencies again using `pod install` (if using Cocoapods)
3. Restart Xcode.
4. Open the `.xcworkspace` file rather than the original `project file` itself.
5. Delete `.xcworkspace` file and `pods` folder from directory and then install the pod dependencies using `pod install`

Comment: i try that but doesn't work the framework is exist in the pods folder but the app can't read it

Comment: Try opening any of the file related to GoogleSignIn Pod

Comment: Another solution would be deleting workspace file and pods folder from directory and reinstalling it on other machine.

Comment: Try 5th Point and let me know if that works or not.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the way I fix this is that every time I get this error, I just close the project and reopen it. While this happens, I think it saves on to my icloud.

Answer (score 0):

For me, It was a Xcode bug on duplicate files.

Step 1: Copy the contents of the file in which there is the error of "No such module ****"

Step 2: Delete the File

Step 3: New a file and Paste the contents.

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem

My mistake is that I put below pod

pod 'GoogleSignIn'

in wrong line in podfile

The right one should be below :

#Pods for ,YOUR APP NAME here,

Then I did install the pods again using the terminal and no more got the error

I hope you to get the solution