# How to get rid of the "No such module 'PromiseKit' error" in 3D Capture sample

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa

I am trying to build the 3D scanning sample provided by the StandardCyborg's Capture SDK for 3D scanning with your iPhone.

I forked their GitHub project and had to make a fix changes to make the project work as you can [see in this forked repo](https://github.com/saamerm/StandardCyborgCocoa/). However, I am not able to get past this issue, "No such module 'PromiseKit'.

I tried to search up the [long list of possible solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500227/getting-error-no-such-module-using-xcode-but-the-framework-is-there) for the "No such module..." error, but neither worked, do you guys know what I can do to get rid of that error?

Creating an API key is free from the standard cyborg website if you want to test their stuff

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: Did you run `pod install` like it says in the readme?

Comment: Yes sir. I ran pod install and promisekit even shows up in the list of linked frameworks for that project

Answer (score 0):

Ah yes, I figured this out. There's two Xcode workspace files in the Standard Cyborg git repo, one inside the `StandardCyborgCocoa` folder and another inside the `StandardCyborgExample` folder.

After following the instructions and doing a `pod install`, I was trying to look at why the Pods are not accessible.
That's when I noticed another workspace file in the example folder. As soon as I opened that workspace, I just had to press build and it worked!