# No such module 'MaterialComponents' only when archiving?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to archive my app, but I get 'No such module 'MaterialComponents' error.
The app runs on simulator and real device.

This is the pod file:
[image]

These are pod frameworks:
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500227/getting-error-no-such-module-using-xcode-but-the-framework-is-there - Did you go through this whole thread?

Answer (score -1):

First of all your running the main target so you never get the error because the error is in a different target. [image], try to run the notification service extension target then you get the error. the basic error is your other target check all the classes that you added in the notification extension you can find that in target membership [image]. it's possible the one of the class is using the 'MaterialComponents' classes. the basic idea is to remove that classes if unwanted if you need that then add the pod into the notification service extension as well, or you can put extension condition in that classes. I had fac issues with my application because it has 3 major target and 5 extension targets.