# XCode archive error 'No such module flutter_downloader' when using AppDelegate.swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter

XCode archive error 'No such module flutter_downloader' when using AppDelegate.swift

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting error "No such module" using Xcode, but the framework is there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500227/getting-error-no-such-module-using-xcode-but-the-framework-is-there)

Comment: no its not that

Comment: please try to clean the project and re-install the pods may help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: how did you sove the issue

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that it's unable to locate the imported `flutter_downloader` package. You can head to the Flutter project folder and run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` to download the plugins again.