# No such module 'Flutter'

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I have published my app in TestFlight but it is crashing while startup. When I view crash logs, it say “No such module 'Flutter’”. I do know how to fix.

Thanks in Advance
￼
[image: Crash Report]

Comment: Does this answer your quetion? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500227/getting-error-no-such-module-using-xcode-but-the-framework-is-there#

Comment: I have same problem with Xcode 14.3. In my case the issue come from I have edit scheme>run as release then I reset scheme>run as debug mode again.

Answer (score 17):

Try this steps. Checked on XCode 14.1

1. Make sure that you open `xcworkspace` instead of `xcodeproj`. `xcworkspace` - contains information about pods.
2. `flutter clean`
3. `flutter pub get`
4. `cd ios; pod install`
5. The error all the same will be display
6. Try to build. Build should be succeeded and the error disappear.

Comment: Most answer just directing for 1 - 4 step, but what remove the error is step 6! bravo, thankyou.

Answer (score 16):

This apparently a bug in XCode 13.1.

It is claimed by Flutter team to be a bug with the visual component of XCode... as evidenced by the fact that the project will still build and run from XCode.

There are many reported ways to get rid of it temporarily, such as doing Product\build , Product\Clean Build Folder, or running the project on IOS from within Android Studio...

But these are only temporary and the problem will reappear.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/92337

Answer (score 15):

Open IOS Folder in terminal ,
write

```
pod install
```

then

```
pod update
```

then it will work

Comment: I did this but still app is crashing.

Comment: not work for me

Answer (score 11):

Need to run both `pod install` and `pod update` as others say, but with extra few steps like below, and this is solved my case:

1. Remove `podfile.lock` file and `Pods` folder
2. Run `pod install` then `pod update`
3. Reopen **`Runner.xcworkspace`** not `Runner.xcodeproj`
4. `No such module Flutter` still exist, just ignore and run as usual
5. `No such module flutter` suddenly disappear after build succeed

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't need to touch `pod` directly. Instead, you can remove `ios/Pods` and then:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter build ios
```

Which has come up in a related issue before, e.g. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/73845#issuecomment-879428744

Answer (score 2):

i just removed `Podfile.lock` and **Pods** folder then run `pod install`

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was me not putting

`install_all_flutter_pods(flutter_application_path)`

in the Podfile
for `target 'my_app'`

I added it for the testing target but not the project...

than `pod install`

```html
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'my_app' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for counter_app
  flutter_application_path = '../flutter_project'
  load File.join(flutter_application_path, '.ios', 'Flutter', 'podhelper.rb')
  install_all_flutter_pods(flutter_application_path)

  target 'my_appTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
    install_all_flutter_pods(flutter_application_path)
  end

  target 'my_appUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
    install_all_flutter_pods(flutter_application_path)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when you have changed your podfile and the pod install command does not work
The piece of code mentioned below is not executing inside your podfile.

```
flutter_install_all_ios_pods
```

Fix this out then run

```
flutter pub get
cd ios && pod install
```