# "Cannot find (<type>) in scope" for all types defined inside my framework, when I reference them in app

Tags: swift, xcode

I wanted to split a common code from my iOS/watchOS/widget app into a separate module (framework) so that it could get built only once (instead of being built again for each target), very much like in [this article](https://www.donnywals.com/breaking-an-app-up-into-modules/).

All targets have the shared module set as a dependency in `Target → Build phases`.

The module with extracted classes builds all right, but when I reference any class from it inside the app, I get `Cannot find '<type name>' in scope` error.

- I verified all such types are defined as public.
- I also tried setting `$(SRCROOT)` as a recursive framework search path for the whole project, as referenced at https://stackoverflow.com/a/31077255/38729 but that didn't help.
- Setting it to `${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/MySharedFrameworkName.framework` didn't help either.
- I also tried to add `import MyAppSharedModule` at the beginning of every file, but I only get `no such module 'MyAppSharedModule'` error.

Thank you for any advice! Everything seems to be in a right place, but compiler (and Xcode when cmd-clicking the type name) cannot find the types.

Comment: did you resolve..?