# I am trying to create IPA(iOS build) for an app where i am facing no such module issue

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am facing an error "No such module 'CashfreePGCoreSDK'" in Xcode 14.2. No other specific reason is displayed to fix the error. Please help me resolve this issue.
Pod install is working fine and i am using cocoapod version: 1.7.5

I have tried installing and uninstalling cashfreePGSDK many times. Besides that, I also cleaned the build folder in Xcode but nothing worked out for me

Comment: This may [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500227/getting-error-no-such-module-using-xcode-but-the-framework-is-there)

Comment: Thanks Vignesh, I had tried it but didn't worked out

Answer (score -1):

Can you try the below options?

- Clean your project: First, try cleaning your project in Xcode by
  going to Product > Clean Build Folder. This will clear out any cached
  files and dependencies and force Xcode to rebuild the project from
  scratch.
- Update your dependences: Make sure that all of your dependencies are
  up-to-date and compatible with the version of Xcode you are using.
  You can do this by running pod update in the Terminal if you are
  using CocoaPods, or updating your package manager if you are using
  another dependency manager.
- Check your project settings: Make sure that your project settings are
  configured correctly. Check the Build Settings for your project and
  make sure that the module is included in the Framework Search Paths
  and Library Search Paths.
- Check your import statements: Double-check your import statements in
  your code and make sure that they match the module name exactly. Make
  sure that the module is spelled correctly and that the case matches.
- Check for typos: Check for any typos or mistakes in your code or
  project settings. For example, if you are using Cocoapods, make sure
  that the Podfile is correctly configured with the correct module name
  and version.
- Try a clean install: If none of the above steps work, you can try
  doing a clean install of your dependencies. This involves deleting
  the Pods directory and the Podfile.lock file, then running pod
  install to reinstall your dependencies.