# Xcode "no such module" error on all cocoapods pods in Mac M1

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I'm trying to compile an app with cocoapods and a lot of pods in Xcode 14 on a mac with M1 processor. The project haves cocoapods and worked perfectly on an old mac.

When compiling, I'm receiving this error on my imports:

> no such module 'devicekit'

If I remove the import, I get the same error for every pod in their imports. When I remove the imports, I get this:

> Cannot find type X in scope
> Value of type X has no member Y

I tried every solution I found in posts like this:
[Getting error "No such module" using Xcode, but the framework is there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500227/getting-error-no-such-module-using-xcode-but-the-framework-is-there)

None of these solutions worked, so I'm sure this must be caused for using a M1 mac.

Comment: Please use a spell-checker when you post questions. "Tryed" would be detected by this (you have 50 others in your post history, and I'd wager 50 have been corrected already).

Comment: @halfer hi, is there an spell checker in stackoverflow?

Comment: @halfer also, how can I check the spell revision count of my post history? thank you

Comment: There is no spell checker in Stack Overflow, but all major browsers have them. If I click Edit on your question, I get the wiggle-red-underline in the edit pane (latest Firefox on Linux Mint). I should think Edge, Chromium, and Safari all do the same.

Comment: You can limit a search to a specific user using the `user:xxx` device. Your ["tryed" posts are here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a479886%20%22tryed%22).

Comment: @halfer now I understand you, but take in mind that my browser is not in english because I don't reside in english language country and my native language is not english, so that spell checker doesn't work exactly like that automatically. But of course I wanna improve and will try to do it better.

Comment: You can (and should) install English as an additional language in your browser. Switching to a different language is two clicks for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I discovered the issue.

In Pods project or in every pod build config you can see that Cocoapods is forcing the "debug" `Build active architecture only` property to `YES`.

```
'Build active architecture only = YES'
```

Changing it manually to `NO` in every pod, did the trick, but that is not a good way to solve it.

You must go to your podfile and add this in the bottom part:

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'NO'
        end
    end
end
```

That will force `NO` to every pod in `Build active architecture only` and the project will start compiling in your M1 mac.